# ThinkPad Yoga 14 : Nvidia Drivers(from ppa) not working

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, thinkpad, nvidia-geforce

It used to work under previous kernel version, but now nvidia-smi simply refuses to see the card:

```
akhavr@yoga14 ~ $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-367 /usr/lib/nvidia-367/bin/nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

The card is there and module picked it up:

```
akhavr@yoga14 ~ $ sudo lspci -k | tail -4
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GM108M [GeForce 840M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

This is the latest kernel from ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
akhavr@yoga14 ~ $ uname -a
Linux yoga14 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and tried different module versions, but none is working for me.  I'll try to remove this ppa and install the version, that comes with the usual repos, but I don't expect it to work either (I've started from such configuration)

It feels like I'm missing something obvious, would appreciate advice.

Upd. Installation of vanilla driver from www.nvidia.com fails, because it's designed to fail: its preinstall script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Trigger an error exit status to prevent the installer from overwriting
# Ubuntu's nvidia packages.

exit 1
```

Upd2. Forced the vanilla installation to continue, yet it fails to load a new `nvidia-drm` module:

```
-> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (367.44):
executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
-> done.
ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module.
```

Upd3. Vanilla nvidia drivers caused infinite login loop.  Returned to the ppa version.

Upd4. After removing all traces of nvidia modules and installing back from ppa, nvidia-smi suddenly sees the card:

```
akhavr@yoga14 ~ $ /usr/lib/nvidia-367/bin/nvidia-smi 
Tue Sep  6 22:56:16 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.44                 Driver Version: 367.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 840M        Off  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    389MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3262    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             165MiB |
|    0      4549    G   compiz                                          35MiB |
|    0      4918    G   ...ves-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-    71MiB |
|    0      5799    G   java                                           115MiB |
|    0      6021    G   unity-control-center                             1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Unfortunately it's picked up by Xorg as a main screen instead of built-in intel card, but that I'll save for another day.

Upd5. Switching to intel card gives me login loop.  Bummer :(

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with the driver posted on Nvidia.com?

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.44/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run

Hope it helps

Comment: As far as I've got, using vanilla nvidia.com drivers is discouraged on ubuntu kernels.  Nevertheless, I'm trying to build the driver now, it barks on my card ("  WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 367.44 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.") and on running X.  Will close X and try to build from pure console

Comment: And, finally, pre-install script fails as designed: "# Trigger an error exit status to prevent the installer from overwriting Ubuntu's nvidia packages."

Comment: Updated original post